# How to check,whether download was successful downloadmanager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download, download-manager

We can catch,when download was finished by using of reciever with intent woith action DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE. But what about checking,whether this download was successful and if no,whether it partially completed or file at this url is not exists. If file is not exists,whether it internet connection problem or something else? If download was paused for some reasons,how to continue it,and whether method of my reciever will call again,when download was completed after resuming ? Because if download unsuccessful i get crash of my app,what not surprisely for me. Thanks everybody very much for any help.

```
//part of my activity class
class ActivityDetails : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var loadId: Long = -1
    private lateinit var dM: DownloadManager
    private val loadReciever: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
                val id: Long = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
                if (id == loadId) {
                        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                            intent.type = dM.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(id)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sharing")
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, dM.getUriForDownloadedFile(id))
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Test")
                        intent.setPackage(null)
                        loadId = -1
                        startActivity(intent)
}
}
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of questions here, please edit your question to focus on one specific issue and show us some code for how you are currently trying to do what you want.

Comment: @sorifiend Ok,i did it.

Comment: `if download unsuccessful i get crash of my app` Where and when? And not needed as you can catch the exception that lets your app crash. Further the broadcast receiver will give you an uri when done.

Comment: @blackapps My app crash with ActivityNotFoundException,but i want to check,whether download was successful without try/catch,if it possible.